# Matriz de bloque

Tags: array, r, matrices, rstudio

Como puedo construir una matriz de bloque a partir de una lista?
Tengo por ejemplo una lista con 3 matrices de distintos tamaños A,B y C

```
 > A
       [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    1    1    1
 [2,]    1    1    1
 [3,]    1    1    1
 > B
       [,1] 
 [1,]    2   
 [2,]    2    
 [3,]    2    

 > C
       [,1] [,2] 
 [1,]    3    3    
 [2,]    3    3    
 [3,]    3    3
```

Una forma de hacerlo es

```
    c1=rbind(A,0*A, 0*A)
    c2=rbind(0*B,B,0*B)
    c3=rbind(0*C,0*C,C)
    MB=cbind(c1,c2,c3)
```

lo que da una matriz de la siguiente forma:

```
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
 [1,]    1    1    1    0    0    0
 [2,]    1    1    1    0    0    0
 [3,]    1    1    1    0    0    0
 [4,]    0    0    0    2    0    0
 [5,]    0    0    0    2    0    0
 [6,]    0    0    0    2    0    0
 [7,]    0    0    0    0    3    3
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    3    3
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    3    3
```

como podria construir la MB (Matriz de bloque) a partir de la lista de matrices sin tener que hacer tanta escritura? El principal problema es que la lista puede ser muy larga, una idea es que podria crear una Matriz de ceros del mismo tamaño pero no he encontrado la forma de ir sustituyendo los elementos donde corresponde

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La construcción de la **matriz bloque** parece emular una especie de diagonal.

Lo anterior implica que se debería trabajar con las dimensiones de cada matriz dentro de la lista como tal y con la suma acumulada de las mismas, es decir:

```
  #            dimensiones                            Matriz Bloque
  #        a secas    acumuladas            subindices              resultado
  #  A  |   3   3   |    3   3       [(1+3-3):3, (1+3-3):3]   |    [1:3, 1:3]
  #  B  |   3   1   |    6   4       [(1+6-3):6, (1+4-1):4]   |    [4:6, 4:4]
  #  C  |   3   2   |    9   6       [(1+9-3):9, (1+6-2):6]   |    [7:9, 5:6]
```

Como las matrices están en una lista se puede emplear `lapply` para hallar sus dimensiones y `Reduce` para definir la dimensión de la **matriz bloque** y las acumuladas respectivas.

Por tanto, el código con sus respectivos comentarios quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
bloque_matriz <- function(mlist){
    # dimensiones de matrices en lista
    dimByMatrix <- lapply(mlist, dim)   

    # dimensiones de la matriz de bloque
    # el signo mas + (obvie el acento 2 veces) va en comillas simples oblicuas
    dim_mb <- Reduce(`+`, dimByMatrix)  

    # dimensiones de matrices acumuladas en la lista
    # recordar el operador +, va en comillas simples oblicuas
    dimAccByMatrix <- Reduce(`+`, dimByMatrix, accumulate = TRUE) 

    # se crea la "matriz bloque" con ceros
    mb <- matrix(0, nrow=dim_mb[1], ncol=dim_mb[2])   

    for (i in 1:length(mlist)){
        a <- dimAccByMatrix[[i]]     # dimension de matrices "acumuladas"
        s <- dimByMatrix[[i]]        # dimension de matrices a "secas" como "son"

        # se recorre la matriz bloque de acuerdo a las dimensiones
        # de cada matriz en la lista, así como los acumulados 
        # calculados previamente y se inserta la matriz correspondiente
        # de la lista
        mb[ (1+a[1]-s[1]):a[1], (1+a[2]-s[2]):a[2] ] <- mlist[[i]]
    } 

    mb  # resultado
}
```

Probando la función `bloque_matriz` con el ejemplo proporcionado:

```
a < -matrix(rep(1,9), nrow = 3)
b <- matrix(rep(2,3), nrow = 3)
c <- matrix(rep(3,6), nrow = 3)

bloque_matriz(list(a, b, c))

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
 [1,]    1    1    1    0    0    0
 [2,]    1    1    1    0    0    0
 [3,]    1    1    1    0    0    0
 [4,]    0    0    0    2    0    0
 [5,]    0    0    0    2    0    0
 [6,]    0    0    0    2    0    0
 [7,]    0    0    0    0    3    3
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    3    3
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    3    3
```